# Elasticsearch, is this "doc_as_upsert" feature in place for NEST client?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d 
{
   "doc" : 
    {
    "name" : "new_name"

    },

    "doc_as_upsert" : true  <======== is this in NEST Client?
}
```

I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not yet but there is a working ticket for it and it will be supported in the next release:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues/368